# php for loop in for loop

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I have a problem trying  using for loop inside a loop  i can't get the result i want

```
<?php
for($sg = 1; $sg <= 11; $sg++){
    echo "<b>".echo $sg;."</b>";

    for($g = 1; $g <= 11; $g++){
        echo "<p>".echo $g."</p>";
    }
?>
```

I looking the result to be like

```
1

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

2

12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

3

21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

continuous ....
```

Comment: So what are you currently getting?

Comment: 1      2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11  -   2  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11  -    3  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

Comment: its repeating the second loop

Comment: First things first, the code you posted is invalid.

Comment: Please clarify the underlying rule that produces your expected output. For the 1st iteration, you're showing 11 values. On the second there's 9, on the third, there's 10. This seems arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
for($sg = 1; $sg <= 11; $sg++){
    echo "<br /> <b>". $sg."</b> ";

    for($g = 1+(10*($sg-1)); $g <= (10*($sg-1))+10; $g++){
        echo "". $g." ";
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
2 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
3 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
4 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
5 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
6 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
7 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
8 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
9 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
10 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
11 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

Comment: This is not OP's intended result.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

$inner_start = 1;
$inner_max = 11;

for($sg = 1; $sg <= 11; $sg++){
    echo "<b>".$sg."</b></br>";   
    
    echo "<p>";
    for($g = $inner_start; $g <= $inner_max; $g++){
        echo $g . ' ';
    }
    $inner_start = $inner_start + 10;
    $inner_max += 10;
    echo "</p></br>";
} 
?>
```